# Confused about the meaning of these nicknames

Tags: words, meaning

I was reading manga the other day and came across these nicknames that I can't make sense of.

The context is as follows: Some mischievous students in a certain high school are bragging about their past. It's a contest to see who is the baddest of the bunch. But one of these students is diligent, and so, they are picking on him.

> 三中の 病院送ら
>
> 二中の 火の玉

As I understand it, this is describing someone who sends people to the hospital, but I have no idea what the `三中の` is referring to. The same goes for the second one.

Some other nicks that I have trouble understanding are

> 不戦勝のマサ
>
> ツ力イツパ

Comment: 病院送り, probably?

Comment: ツカイッパ (note the small ッ) is come from 使{つか}いっ走{ぱし}り.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[三中]{さんちゅう}」 is a nickname for a junior high school that is officially named 「〇〇第三中学校」.　The 〇〇 part is usually a town or area name.  Many public schools in Japan are named using ***ordinal numbers*** like that.

So, it is like saying "(area name) 3rd Junior High School"

[image]
<sub>(source: [ikora.tv](http://img01.ikora.tv/usr/sakakibarakainan/%E6%A0%A1%E9%96%80.JPG))</sub>

***NOTE***: Contrary to what has been stated by another user in his/her answer, 「三中」 has nothing to do with 「中三」.  The latter means "the third year in junior high school".

Moving on...

「[不戦勝]{ふせんしょう}」means "a win by default".  「マサ」 is a common nickname for guys whose full given names include 「まさ」.

不戦勝のマサ must be so strong that he never actually gets to fight because the other guys always run away at the sight of him.  However you translate that is up to you as long as you know what it means.  The 「の」 here is appositional.

Lastly, 「ツ力イツパ」...

The second 「ツ」 would have to be the small 「ッ」.  It would make no sense otherwise.

「ツカイッパ」 is short for 「つかいっぱしり」(使いっぱしり) , which means "**gofer**".

In real life, it is shortened to 「パシリ」 much more often.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the definition to the word 三中 in [weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/wkpja/content/%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%AD_%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AE%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81). The third bullet point reads "common abbreviation for third middle school across all country".
(edited. check the comments below for reason)

For 不戦勝のマサ, I found the following line in the manga's wiki:

> ゴツい外見ゆえに相手が勝手に委縮してケンカを売ってこないため、今まで一度も喧嘩をしたことがなく、自分でも喧嘩の実力が分からない。このため、中学時代は「不戦勝のマサ」というあだ名をつけられた。

It says something along the lines (rough translation due to laziness) of

> "Because of my tough appearance, no one picked a fight with me, even now I've never got into a fight and I don't even know my true fighting power. Because of that, in middle school I was called 不戦勝のマサ."

It seems マサ is the name of the character, so it's "マサ who wins without fighting".

No idea about what ツ力イツパ might be.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mixed up 中三 with 三中?

Comment: I checked and you are wrong.  As a Japanese-speaker, I actually knew you were wrong even before I checked.  (Public) schools are often "numbered" instead of given unique names.  Those numbers have absolutely nothing to do with grades (years) that students belong in.

Comment: You're right. My bad.

Comment: @l'électeur While "you are wrong" was technically correct even without repeating it twice, isn't this site about Q and A? "This answer is wrong" sounds more appropriate here, imho.